# Getting mouse down event in blender via python

Tags: python, mouse, blender

I am trying to create a script for blender that needs mouse events; however i cannot find any that are not utilizing either the grease pencil or are specifically for the blender game engine.

Im trying to create a script that will make my retopology workflow better ,but ive been stuck on this problem for most of the day. So far i have a script that turns on snap to faces creates a new mesh at the center point of your mesh and applies a mirror modifier. What i want to be able to do is then create a listener that will capture mouse events and when you hold down the left mouse it will create vertices every couple of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a modal operator, you will find a few examples in the python templates available in blender's text editor.

More specifically you would want to look at the `Operator Modal View3D Raycast`

You will probably find [cgcookies retopology tools](http://cgcookiemarkets.com/blender/?s=retopology) inspirational if not suitable for the task you are trying to do.

Comment: Ive tried that tool and while contours works fine the polystips tool is too heavy to work on my machine well. So im trying to make my own that will be lighter and as a way to learn python. Ive seen it done before and after some research ive decided to use the grease pencil.